# Any official size for the ISS pizza box?

Tags: iss, collision-avoidance

I still haven't found the official size of the ISS *pizza box*<sup>[1]</sup> and a search on the WEB doesn't help:

"30 miles deep and 30 miles long around the space station": https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/3dkpyn/international-space-station-dodge-space-junk

"two kilometers above and below the station and 25 kilometers cross-track and down-track": https://arstechnica.com/science/2013/07/how-nasa-steers-the-international-space-station-around-space-junk/

"±25 km in the direction of motion, ±25 km perpendicular to the direction of motion, and ±0.5 km radially from the ISS as it flies in orbit": https://books.google.de/books?id=9mseNE1wkLMC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145#v=onepage&q&f=false

"0.75 kilometers above and below the station and 25 kilometers on each side": https://www.universetoday.com/92571/iss-will-do-manuever-friday-to-avoid-collision-with-satellite-debris/

Is there any official size?

**EDIT**

<sup>[1]</sup>*Pizza box*: a safety region around the ISS. Please, see the 3<sup>rd</sup> link page 145 for an authoritative definition, which, in fact, answers my question (from that preview I didn't realize it was published by NASA).

Comment: Not sure what you're gonna get more authoritative than the 3rd link, which is an official NASA document. Unfortunately, NASA does not post ISS flight rules.

Comment: From that preview I didn't realize it was published by NASA. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I had written an answer based on the same document. I didn't recognize it from the link. So I deleted the answer.  The document contains a good overview of the COLA process.

Comment: I suggest adding a definition of the "pizza box" at the top of the question. I would do it by myself but my english skills are not too good.

Comment: no pizza available here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20816/12102 and the link to the source is now broken

Comment: @uhoh there is a copy here: https://dokumen.tips/documents/iss-cots-interface-requirements-document-ssp-50808-ssp-50808-is-an-itar-controlled.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned this in a comment, but an official answer is needed.

The document in your 3rd link is the official-as-it-gets NASA document [The International Space Station - Operating an Outpost in the New Frontier](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss-operating_an_outpost-tagged.pdf)

The ISS Flight Rules would be the authoritative source, but NASA does not publish them.

[image]

From p.145 in the link.